# Most optimized/efficient way to update Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a data set with more than 10000 (this will be more in future) records as below:

```
[[name=>'name1',url=>'url1', visit=>120],
[name=>'name2',url=>'url2'], visit=>250,
..........
]
```

It is possible to have duplicate values for the `key` combination `name`,`url`. In such situations I need to get the sum of each records have the duplicate `name`,`url`.

Finally I want insert this values into a database. When I do this I have two method to do this:

1. Create another array with unique combination (name,url) and sum of visit
2. Update/insert db for each record in a loop.

What is the optimal solution to do this or is there *better* way to do this?

I know there will be memory issues for a large data set in the first method. In second method there are many `db` hits and I need to know the disadvantage(s) if I follow 2nd way.

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using PDO or mysqli?

Comment: @michael, I'm using mysqli

Comment: mysql? without an **i** at the end? If so, that's the first tip I have for you - don't use mysql! It's deprecated/will be. Best use PDO, or mysqli if you don't like PDO. You should be able to use something like INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... for the dupe problem. Are you able to convert the data array you have to (better) xml or csv? I use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE for big inserts (10000 isn't big, but you said it's getting more). I would most propably create a temporary table for the load data local infile and then calculate while copying the raw data from the temp to the main table

Comment: actually the data set is not an array. I have to get that data from GA as batches. when I get that data as batches I have to create one array,file, or temp table because when I get the next batch I need to have the data of previous batch. The data can be grow according to the events and custom variables. If I use a file to store data I have to search the matches for (name,url) in the file for each record. Can you explain best way for this. Thank you for the kind help )

Answer (score -1):

I do some big database update like this myself and spent ages trying different solutions.

Instead of:

1. Check if record exists, eg select count(id) from data where
   name='name' and url='url'
2. Not found, insert record
3. Found, sum result

I would try this

1. Set the unique primary keys on your data table on the url and name field.
2. Try to do a normal insert and see if you get a successful result.
3. On unsuccessful result (there already is value for name and url because these 2 fields must be unique), sum the result.

Comment: thanks for the help, But if I follow this way there will be more than 10000 db requests for this. in future it will be increase more. I need to know will this be a performance issue or any other issue for my function.